# Normalisation Performance: allIds array vs Object.entries function

Tags: javascript, redux, normalization

In redux and other situations, we may want to normalize JavaScript objects which are relational in nature, rather than have deeply nested objects.

For example, redux shows a recipe which suggests splitting your code as such:

```
const byID = {
  '1': {
    some: 'object'
  },
  '2': {
    some: 'objectAgain'
  },
  '3': {
    some: 'objectAnotherAgain'
  },
};
const allIds = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

[Redux Recommended Recipe](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape#designing-a-normalized-state)

However, what is the advantage of holding that allIds array, vs just calling something similar to the following:

```
Object.keys(byId);
```

[Object Keys Recipe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Is holding all the object keys as an array faster? Or are they of similar time complexity? Would holding each key in the array not be duplicate code?

Comment: One, possibly important, difference is that you can count on the order for `allIds` but not `Object.keys(byId)`.

Comment: Object.keys(byId) returns exaxtly the same array as allIds, but the purpose of redux is to store all the data as flat as possible in one object, right? Calling the .keys() method outside of the object and not saving it would be kind of the opposite of that...

Comment: @StephanT. I see that perspective now. I'm happy to potentially mark that as a correct answer? Seeing as it does help me with my decision on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.keys(byId) returns exaxtly the same array as allIds, but the purpose of redux is to store all the data **as flat as possible** in **one object**, right? Calling the Object.keys() method outside of the object and not saving it would be kind of the opposite of that...

```js
var array = {
  posts: {
    byId: {
      "post1": {
        id: "post1",
        author: "user1",
        body: "......",
        comments: ["comment1", "comment2"]
      },
      "post2": {
        id: "post2",
        author: "user2",
        body: "......",
        comments: ["comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]
      }
    },
    allIds: ["post1", "post2"]
  },
  comments: {
    byId: {
      "comment1": {
        id: "comment1",
        author: "user2",
        comment: ".....",
      },
      "comment2": {
        id: "comment2",
        author: "user3",
        comment: ".....",
      },
      "comment3": {
        id: "comment3",
        author: "user3",
        comment: ".....",
      },
      "comment4": {
        id: "comment4",
        author: "user1",
        comment: ".....",
      },
      "comment5": {
        id: "comment5",
        author: "user3",
        comment: ".....",
      },
    },
    allIds: ["comment1", "comment2", "comment3", "commment4", "comment5"]
  },
  users: {
    byId: {
      "user1": {
        username: "user1",
        name: "User 1",
      },
      "user2": {
        username: "user2",
        name: "User 2",
      },
      "user3": {
        username: "user3",
        name: "User 3",
      }
    },
    allIds: ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
  }
}

var keys = Object.keys(array.users.byId);
console.log(keys); // need to call a function where i should already know what i want
var simpleKeys = array.users.allIds
console.log(simpleKeys); // way faster too
```

> Relevant links:
>
> - [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
> - [normalized state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape#designing-a-normalized-state)